# No $_POST data?

Tags: php, post

**EDIT** - I have closed this post, as I can only conclude that there is a problem with the current build of PHP on the server.  PHP is accepting $_GET variables no problem, but any attempt of receiving/sending $_POST variables fails entirely.

I have a silly little form:

```
<form action="http://www.domain.com/login" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="loginPage" value="login">
    <table class="login">   
        <tr><td>Email Address</td><td><input type="text" class="txt" name="usr"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" class="txt" name="psw"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" class="submit right" value="Log in"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And I am not recieving any ANY data in my $_POST.  Right at the top of the page I dump:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and I get:

```
array(0) { }
```

Which is very annoying.

Anyone know why?

**EDIT**

There IS url rewriting, see the following (from .HTACCESS):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html
AddType "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" txt

RewriteRule ^login$ "login.php" [NC]
RewriteRule ^login/$ "login.php" [NC]
```

But i cant see anything wrong with that, and when we set it up, it was working fine? Just seems that something has been changed (its not my server) recently?  But what else could be getting in the way?

Comment: have you added code when form is posted...?

Comment: Is the path to the action correct ?

Comment: Check your sever setting..

Comment: Unless your using some URL rewriting you'll want to add the file extension to the action. (See Yogesh Suthar's answer)

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the post request in your browser's dev tools (chrome network tab, for example)? Have a look there and see if the request contains post data. A brief look at your code doesn't show anything wrong.

Comment: Have you used url rewrite?

Comment: Please learn to love [the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/).

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Yes it is

Comment: @Quentin what is the point of the label element?

Comment: [`var_dump($_SERVER);` please](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server)

Comment: @Chud37 — The link in my last comment explains

Comment: @Chud37 I made an exact replicate of your code, and it works here. Is the apache rewrite module enabled ? Are you displaying errors ?

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the real URL it is hard to be sure, but a likely explanation is:

Your PHP program is really at `/login/index.php` so when the browser makes a POST request to `/login` the server responds with a `301 Redirect` to `/login/`.

This causes the browser to make a GET request to `/login/` and `$_POST` will be empty.

If this is the case, the solution is to use `action="http://example.com/login/"` (with a `/` on the end).

Comment: see the redirect .htaccess above - the login.php page is refering to itself which is in the root.

Comment: the trailing slash made no difference either :(

Comment: @Chud37 does it work when you set in action direct path to your `login.php`, without `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: @MarkoD I completely removed the .htaccess and directedt the form to login.php, still the same results.  I cannot work this one out.

Comment: @Chud37 post the full code of your files, copy/paste please

Comment: @MarkoD Why? You have the form, and the fact that on the first line of the script var_dump($_POST) returns nothing.  The rest of the page does not have any bearing on it.

Comment: @Chud37 you would be surprised how many times people here say "it's just that, why I need to post the rest", but it turns not to be the case. I am not saying it will be the case now, but just to make sure we're not debugging unexisting problem

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<form action="http://www.domain.com/login" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="http://www.domain.com/login.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: what if OP used url `rewrite`.??

Comment: what if we ask OP instead of guessing?

Comment: @MarkoD Probably a good idea

Comment: @DipeshParmar OP **DID** use URL rewrite.

Comment: @Chud37 i think you are the OP....

Comment: @DipeshParmar I was refering to my self in third person.

Comment: @Chud37 instead of chit-chat, you may want to look at Quentin's answer and report if that solved the problem

Comment: @MarkoD thanks for keeping me on the straight and narrow.  I was simply indulging the conversation - I did not start it.